# How to get this pipeline to return exactly one document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running the following aggregation pipeline:

```
const agg = [
  {
    '$match': {
      'aaa': 'bbb'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '', 
      'total': {
        '$sum': '$num'
      }
    }
  }
];
```

My problem is, when `$match` matches nothing, the pipeline returns 0 documents. How do I get the pipeline to always return 1 document?

Comment: You say "when $match matches nothing you get 0 docs in response from mongo". Why is it a problem? Why not adding "if result.isEmpty -> return OneDefaultDoc" @ backend? What should be a default document? Bottom line `$match` is like `WHERE` clause in SQL, it behaves correctly, please add more details to the question

Comment: I didn't ask whether $match behaves correctly, I asked how to change the pipeline to do what I need it to do.  One use case is when the pipeline contains more stages. 

The default document should be {_id: '', total: 0}

Comment: Which version of MongoDB do you run?

Comment: Ideally, 4.2, but it would be good to know what 6 can do, too.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB version 6.0 you can do it like this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { aaa: 'bbb' } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         total: { $sum: "$num" }
      }
   },
   {
      $densify: {
         field: "total",
         range: { step: 1, bounds: [0, 0] }
      }
   },
   { $set: { _id: { $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: "$_id" }, "missing"] }, MaxKey, "$_id"] } } },
   { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
   { $limit: 1 }
])
```

In version < 6.0 you can try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $facet: {
         data: [
            { $match: { aaa: 'bbb' } },
            { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$num" } } }
         ],
         default: [
            { $limit: 1 },
            { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: 0 } } },
            { $set: { _id: MaxKey } }
         ]
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: [{ $first: "$default" }, { $first: "$data" }] } },
])
```

Or this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { aaa: 'bbb' } },
   { $group: { _id: null, total: { $sum: "$num" } } },
   {
      $unionWith: {
         coll: "collection",
         pipeline: [
            { $limit: 1 },
            { $set: { _id: MaxKey, total: 0 } },
            { $project: { _id: 1, total: 1 } }
         ]
      }
   },
   { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
   { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Comment: That second option (for before `6.0`) is going to force a full collection scan which probably isn't a viable approach in production. Might be worth mentioning that in the answer to avoid some confusion or surprises later

Comment: Added `{ $limit: 1 }` which should prevent the full collection scan.

Comment: I don't think that's how it works. You can see a collection scan of all 12 sample documents in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k-XPdBNJvym), or a much simpler one [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/279J7sngup7)

Comment: See my 3rd solution